# Pandas: how to change a Series into nested list by index

Tags: python, pandas

My Series look like this:

```
group
SAM         1
SAM         1
PEG-PROD    1
TAG         1
PEG-PROD    1
SAM         1
PEG-MAR     1
SIG-A       1
SAM         1
PEG-MAR     1
```

I wanna change it into a nested list based on group like this:

```
SAM 1,1,1,1
PEG-PROD 1,1
PEG_MAR 1,1
TAG 1
SIG-A 1
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
s.groupby(s.index).apply(list)
```

where `s` is your Series

Comment: Thanks, Kartik. That's great! But when I draw a boxplot, the group name (index) doesn't show. `plt.boxplot(lst_times_chip_used)`, do I need to add some param?